# Django. module 'articles.apps' has no attribute 'ArticleConfig'

Tags: django

Вот часть кода settings

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'articles.apps.ArticleConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Вот код models

```
from django.db import models

    class Article(models.Model):
        article_title = models.CharField('Название статьи', max_length = 200)
        article_text = models.TextField('Текст статьи')
        pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Дата публикации')
    class Comment(models.Model):
        article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
        author_name = models.CharField('Имя автора', max_length = 100)
        comment_text = models.CharF
```

Вот код apps

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class ArticlesConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'articles'
```

Я переходил на связанные темы, но именно общего с этой проблемы не нашел. Я добавил в settings приложение.

```
D:\Django\myfirst>python manage.py makemigrations articles
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Таирлан\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-pack
ages\django\apps\config.py", line 118, in create
    cls = getattr(mod, cls_name)
AttributeError: module 'articles.apps' has no attribute 'ArticleConfig'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Таирлан\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-pack
ages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line

    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Таирлан\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-pack
ages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\Таирлан\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-pack
ages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Таирлан\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-pack
ages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\Таирлан\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-pack
ages\django\apps\config.py", line 132, in create
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'articles.apps' does not contain a
class 'ArticleConfig'. Choices are: 'ArticlesConfig'.

D:\Django\myfirst>
```

Comment: Проблема очевидна. У вас `ArticlesConfig `, а в  `INSTALLED_APPS `  добавлен `articles.apps.ArticleConfig`.  Буквы `s` не хватает. Вам, кстати об этом и говорит ошибка `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'articles.apps' does not contain a
class 'ArticleConfig'. Choices are: 'ArticlesConfig'.`

Comment: Спасибо. Я делал как в видео, у него без,s но работает. Спасибо.